# Should I use python or numpy functions?

Tags: python, numpy

Python offers a few methods which are also implemented in python:

Power: `x ** 2` vs. `np.power(x,2)`

Matrix muliplication elementwise: `X * Y` vs. `np.multiply(X,Y)`

Sum: `sum(X)` vs. `np.sum(X)`

etc.

So, what I wonder now: Are the implementations in numpy more efficient than the native ones in Python or doesn't it matter at all?

Comment: Please spend at least 5 mins with numpy's documentation to see what exactly is faster under what circumstances. Mostly it boils down to scalars vs. arrays.

Comment: What results did you get when you tried timing these? (Hint: take a look at the %timeit magic command in IPython.) I'd suggest doing some timings and coming back with a more specific question (e.g.: "Why is `x**2` 30 times faster than `np.power(x, 2)` for a 1d array `x` of 1 million floats?", the answer to which is non-obvious).

Comment: It totally depends on the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

These are different cases.  Operators versus functions, Python list functions versus numpy array functions.

```
Power: x ** 2 vs. np.power(x,2)
```

Python translates `x**2` into `x.__pow__(2)`, thus delegating the task to the `pow` method of `x`.  If `x` is an array, then it is using the array version of `pow`.  `np.power` probably does the same, after converting to `x` to an array if needed.  Some times this numpy function delegation can be seen in Python code.  Here `np.power` is compiled.

```
Matrix muliplication elementwise: X * Y vs. np.multiply(X,Y)
```

Likewise `X*Y` becomes `X.__mul__(Y)`.  `np.multiply` is a numpy `ufunc`, a category of operators with added functionality (like `accumulate`, `reduceat`, etc).  It also has a number of parameters (`out`, `casting` etc) that aren't available with the operator version.

```
Sum: sum(X) vs. np.sum(X)
```

There is a Python `sum`, which treats it's input as a list.  `np.sum` converts its input into an array and then sums.

As a general rule, if the operator version works for your variables use it.  That would apply to numeric scalars and arrays.  Lists typically have  their own versions of those operators (e.g. `[1,2,3]*3` or `[1,2,3]+[4,5]`).  Use the numpy function version if it makes your code clearer (to you), or if you need it to first convert the input to an array.

In special cases one version or the other will be faster, but that shouldn't be the first consideration. Getting correct and clear code has priority.

Comment: It may be worth noting that `x**2` versus `np.power(x, 2)` is a bit of an unusual case: `x.__pow__(2)` will [special-case the exponent `2`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/75b2d5d427afdb1392f2a0b2092e0767e4bab53d/numpy/core/src/multiarray/number.c#L473) and use a squaring operation; so for large arrays, `x**2` can be an order of magnitude faster than `np.power(x, 2)` (which doesn't do such special casing).

Answer (score 0):

The speed of the various functions that you mention depend on the data types that are passed to them as well as the size of the arrays. My advice would be to sit down with some realistic data for your application and use `timeit` to benchmark the functions. In general though, when operation on numpy arrays, the functions provided by numpy will be much faster than the python builtins.